# Copy path from context menu, edit, replaced clipboard with edited text

Tags: windows, lua, registry, clipboard, autohotkey

A long time ago I added a context menu entry that allows me to copy path of selected file/folder to the clipboard.

The registry key value is `cmd.exe /c (echo.|set /p="%1") | clip`

(An aside: I have since discovered that holding shift when right-clicking will give the same Copy as Path option, but this doesn't suit me anyway for 2 reasons. I have to hold shift, and, my registry addition removes the double quotation marks from the path, which suits my needs better. And I cant find the windows version in the registry anyway.)

Anyway I am now in a situation where am writing a lot of .lua code (for custom Unified Remote's, great app). It requires slashes to be forward, not backward. I was hoping to alter code to replace slashes on clipboard. I thought this might be possible after using an Auto Hotkey script to [change case](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/24431-convert-text-uppercase-lowercase-capitalized-or-inverted/page-3) , hoped that something simple might exist in command line to be called from registry.

If anyone can think of a different, efficient way to do it I'm happy to change tack. Just seems this would be simplest, eg.

[image]

I know I can paste into text editor then Replace All etc, but much more time consuming with multiple addresses.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for getting me on the right track @user3419297. I made these changes and got it working:
 1. Changed script path in .reg file to C:\Scripts\Copy as Path (Lua).exe %1 It gave me a permission denied error without this change. Note it still (as in the original .reg file) doesn't add the value to the command key automatically, I had to manually add it.
 2. Replaced the // with / in the .ahk script. Otherwise it didn't replace slashes.
I then got a working script that pasted the *short* filename, so I altered the script with A_LoopFileLongPath, this is finished working script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Ignore
SetBatchLines -1
#NoTrayIcon 

FileGetAttrib, a, %1%

Loop %1%, 1
    Longpath = %A_LoopFileLongPath%

clipboard = %Longpath%
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, \, /, All
```

Works great :)